# Kotlin is filtering list before getting max value best apporach?

Tags: kotlin

If you have a list of objects object(category, value) and want to get the max value excluding some categories you can use something like this:

```
val max = objects.filter { it.category.name != xy }.maxByOrNull { it.value }
```

But this uses 2 iterators if I understand it correctly, so would there be a more performant version of this call using only one iterator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's correct. This code will first iterate over the whole list to filter the result, and then again to find the max.

I'll detail some alternatives below, but, overall, I would recommend against any of them without a very good justification. The performance benefits are usually marginal - spending time making sure the code is clear and well tested will be a better investment. I'd recommend sticking to your existing code.

#### Example

Here's an executable version of your code.

```kotlin
fun main() {

  val items = listOf(
    MyData("shoes", 1),
    MyData("shoes", 22),
    MyData("shoes", 33),
    MyData("car", 555),
  )

  val max = items
    .filter {
      println("  filter $it")
      it.categoryName == "shoes"
    }.maxByOrNull {
      println("  maxByOrNull $it")
      it.value
    }

  println("\nresult: $max")
}
```

There are two iterations, and each are run twice.

```
  filter MyData(categoryName=shoes, value=1)
  filter MyData(categoryName=shoes, value=22)
  filter MyData(categoryName=shoes, value=33)
  filter MyData(categoryName=car, value=555)
  maxByOrNull MyData(categoryName=shoes, value=1)
  maxByOrNull MyData(categoryName=shoes, value=22)
  maxByOrNull MyData(categoryName=shoes, value=33)

result: MyData(categoryName=shoes, value=33)
```

#### Sequences

In some situations you can use [sequences](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/sequences.html) to reduce the number of operations.

```kotlin
  val max2 = items
    .asSequence()
    .filter {
      println("  filter $it")
      it.categoryName == "shoes"
    }.maxByOrNull {
      println("  maxByOrNull $it")
      it.value
    }

  println("\nresult: $max2")
```

As you can see, the order of operations is different

```
  filter MyData(categoryName=shoes, value=1)
  filter MyData(categoryName=shoes, value=22)
  maxByOrNull MyData(categoryName=shoes, value=1)
  maxByOrNull MyData(categoryName=shoes, value=22)
  filter MyData(categoryName=shoes, value=33)
  maxByOrNull MyData(categoryName=shoes, value=33)
  filter MyData(categoryName=car, value=555)

result: MyData(categoryName=shoes, value=33)
```

> [S]equences let you avoid building results of intermediate steps, therefore improving the performance of the whole collection processing chain.

Note that in this small example, the benefits aren't worth it.

> However, the lazy nature of sequences adds some overhead which may be significant when processing smaller collections or doing simpler computations.

#### Combining operations

In your small example you could combine the 'filter' and 'maxBy' operations

```kotlin
  val max3 = items.maxByOrNull { data ->
    when (data.categoryName) {
      "shoes" -> data.value
      "car"   -> -1
      else    -> -1
    }
  }
  println("\nresult: $max3")
```

```
result: MyData(categoryName=shoes, value=33)
```

I hope it's clear that this solution isn't immediately understandable, and has some nasty edge cases that would be a prime source of bugs. I won't detail the issues, but instead re-iterate that ease-of-use, adaptability, and simple code is usually much more valuable than optimised code!

Comment: Could you please explain in simple words your combining operations solution, so following readers understand it easily

Comment: @David If something is unclear then please ask, or if you have a suggestion for an explanation I can add it.

Comment: @aSemy David _has_ asked… :-) I think the combined code is making two implicit assumptions: that the `value` is always ≥ 0, and that there will always be at least one non-excluded item. The code works by treating excluded items as if they have a value of -1, which will never be selected as the max because (by assumptions) there will always be a value ≥ 0 to be selected instead. — Of course, one or both assumptions may be wrong, in which case this code will fail (returning -1 when it should be a lower number or null)…

Comment: It could be adapted to handle -ve values by replacing `-1` with `Int.MIN_VALUE` — then it can be sure there can never be a lower `value` present. Alternatively, the same change could handle every item being excluded — _if_ no genuine value was `Int.MIN_VALUE`, and it appended `.takeIf{ it > Int.MIN_VALUE }` so that the overall result was null if all items were excluded. However, I can't see any way to adapt this code to remove _both_ assumptions. — And in any case, there should be comments explaining assumptions and non-obvious bits of processing like this.

Comment: Based on @gidds' comments then again we are there where I think that it would be better to iterate manually I suppose. Btw. using android micro benchmarking I got 186ns and 1 alloc for the combining solution, 369ns and 4alloc for sequence and 380ns and 4 alloc with aggregation